# Title сайтов из списка в файле

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, parse

Можно ли, чтобы r = requests.get брал адреса сайтов из файла? Или же мне надо создать массив с адресами сайтов? Там просто их более 400

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("sites.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()



r = requests.get(lines)


with open('html.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        output_file.write(r.text)


html = open('html.html', encoding="utf-8").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')


title = soup.find('title')

print(title)
```

Мне нужен title всех сайтов из списка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли, чтобы r = requests.get брал адреса сайтов из файла? Или же

Нельзя, он принимает только строку-адрес сайта

> мне надо создать массив с адресами сайтов?

Угу (вариант с `.readlines()`), либо, если серьезные ограничения по памяти, то можно сделать перебор строк из файла в цикле

Пример:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("sites.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    url = line.strip()

    rs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find('title')
    print(title.get_text(strip=True))
```

---

**PS.**

- `url = line.strip()` тут `strip` используется, чтобы убрать пробелы и символы перехода на новую строку `\n`, а `readlines` обязательно их вернет
- `soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')`

  - нет смысла сохранять в файл ответ от запроса, поэтому сразу используется
  - `rs.content` возвращает ответ как байтовый массив, это даст `BeautifulSoup` самому определить кодировку из ответа
  - `'html.parser'` это питоничий парсер html, нет нужды использовать сторонние библиотеки, типа `lxml`
- `get_text(strip=True)` метод возвращает текстовое представление элемента с удалением пробельных символов (аналог `.strip()`)